# Как узнать какой элемент был нажат первым?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

У меня через делегирование события отлавливается нажатие.

Если 5 элементов один из них со значением `value = 1`. Блок с value при нажатии закрашывается зеленым при етом увеличиваеться значение і, в противном случае красным і не изменяеться.

Важно чтобы после первого нажатия на красный блок, второй не нажымался, или значение i не увеличивалося если блок со значением `value = 1` был нажат не при первом нажатии.

```
if (target.getAttribute('value') == 1) {
  selectedSpan.classList.add('test__answer--green');
  i++;
}

if (target.hasAttribute('value') === false) {
  selectedSpan.classList.add('test__answer--red');
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте объяснить понятнее. Чётко и ясно в чем проблема. И прежде чем сюда вставлять код - отформатируйте его.

Comment: Да, правильнее и проще всего заблокировать второй элемент.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('parent').onclick = function() {
  if (event.target.value  == true) {
    document.getElementById('color-me').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    return;
  }
  document.getElementById('color-me').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input type="button" value="1" />
  <input type="button" value="0" />
</div>
<div id="color-me" style="width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid;margin:5px"></div>
```

Comment: после нажатия на первую кнопку вторая всеравно нажимаеться

Comment: у вас с в вопросе обозначено "или". Было, по крайней мере, до того как вы отредактировали вопрос.

Comment: извиняюсь за неправильную формулировку, можно как то сделать что бы после нажатия на один, другой уже был не активным?

Answer (score 0):

`on("click", function(" var time=Date.now()"))` и простая операция сравнения

Comment: можно поподробнее?